# Windows 10 taskbar always showing in auto-hide

Tags: windows-10

Although i've set my task bar to auto-hide, it will shows up randomly, even if my mouse cursor is on top of the screen. To hide it, i need to click twice on Start menu.

This is very frustrating, how to fix ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Settings first. Set the Taskbar to Auto Hide to be sure it is set. Then change the Taskbar to Locked. Close out restart and test the Taskbar operation. The Taskbar should remain locked when not changing it. This prevents unwanted changes.

Be sure Auto Hide is set for just Desktop and not Tablet (that is, not both).

If Settings does not work, run the initial Windows 10 repair procedures.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run both:

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth AND
SFC /SCANNOW

Close out, restart and test.

I have tested Auto Hide thoroughly and it works fine. It hides as soon as the mouse moves away without clicking on anything

Comment: This won't work. Once i move my mouse to the bottom, the taskbar shows and it will hide only if i click on Start menu twice. The behaviour i expect would be it hide when the mouse isn't on the bottom of the screen

Comment: I have edited my post to provide initial repairs if settings do not work.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain what exactly will this command perform ?

Comment: They are repair steps to fix Windows System files.  Also, on your computer turn off Auto Hide in Tablet mode. Just have it in Desktop mode